# The console window of VScode(visual studio code) closes immediately

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Using the 'scanf', the console does not open properly. The visual studio code is too difficult. This is the first code. Please help me set the environment.

Comment: Minor suggestions: a) add a prompt output before the `scanf`. There is nothing less informative than a blank screen when you run a program. b) add a final newline to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Does it answer your question?
[system("pause"); - Why is it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong)

> Using system("pause"); is Ungood Practice™ because
>
> It's completely unnecessary. To keep the program's console window open
> at the end when you run it from Visual Studio, use Ctrl+F5 to run it
> without debugging, or else place a breakpoint at the last right brace
> } of main. So, no problem in Visual Studio. And of course no problem
> at all when you run it from the command line.
>
> It's problematic & annoying when you run the program from the command
> line. For interactive execution you have to press a key at the end to
> no purpose whatsoever. And for use in automation of some task that
> pause is very much undesired!
>
> It's not portable. Unix-land has no standard pause command.
>
> The pause command is an internal cmd.exe command and can't be
> overridden, as is erroneously claimed in at least one other answer.
> I.e. it's not a security risk, and the claim that AV programs diagnose
> it as such is as dubious as the claim of overriding the command (after
> all, a C++ program invoking system is in position to do itself all
> that the command interpreter can do, and more). Also, while this way
> of pausing is extremely inefficient by the usual standards of C++
> programming, that doesn't matter at all at the end of a novice's
> program.
>
> So, the claims in the horde of answers before this are not correct,
> and the main reason you shouldn't use system("pause") or any other
> wait command at the end of your main, is the first point above: it's
> completely unnecessary, it serves absolutely no purpose, it's just
> very silly.